# Append a delay to each chunk with the streaming library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-streaming

newbie to Streaming and Haskell here.

I've been playing around with the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library and I'm particularly interested in understanding the chunks part. Eg:

```
S.print $ S.delay 1.0 $ concats $ chunksOf 2 $ S.each [1..10]
```

Or:

```
S.print $ concats $ S.maps (S.delay 1.0) $ chunksOf 2 $ S.each [1..10]
```

Here I can introduce a delay after each element but what I want is to have a delay after each chunk, in this case a delay every second element. I tried this but doesn't compile:

```
S.print $ concats $ S.delay 1.0 $ chunksOf 2 $ S.each [1..10]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need is a function that inserts a single delay at the end of a chunk stream, and pass that function to [`maps`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:maps).

[`delay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:delay) doesn't work here because it put delays between each yielded value. But we can do it easily using functions from [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42-):

```
  S.print 
$ concats 
$ S.maps (\s -> s <* liftIO (threadDelay 1000000)) 
$ chunksOf 2 
$ S.each [1..10]
```

What is happening here? [`maps`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:maps) applies a transformation to the "base functor" of the `Stream`. In a "chunked stream" obtained with [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:chunksOf), that base functor is *itself* a `Stream`. Also, the transformation must preserve the return value of the `Stream`.

`Stream`s can be sequenced with functions like [`(>>=) :: Stream f m a -> (a -> Stream f m b) -> Stream f m b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-) if the next stream depends on the final result of the previous one, or with functions like [`(<*) :: Stream f m a -> Stream f m b -> Stream f m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42-) if it doesn't. `(<*)` preserves the return value of the first `Stream`, which is what we want in this case.

We do not want to yield any more elements, but only to introduce a delay effect, so we simply `liftIO` the effect into the `Stream` monad.

---

Another way to insert delays after each yielded value of a `Stream` is to [zip it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:zipWith) with an [infinite list](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:repeatM) of delays:

```
delay' :: MonadIO m => Int -> Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of a) m r
delay' micros s = S.zipWith const s (S.repeatM (liftIO (threadDelay micros)))
```